# How to change image displayed in sectionHeader

Tags: visualforce, css

Is there anyway to change the image displayed in the sectionHeader

Here is what I have:

```
<apex:sectionHeader title="Dollor Store"/>
```

By default it displays this icon:

```
Custom42Tab .pageTitleIcon, .individualPalette .Custom42Block .pageTitleIcon {
    background-image: url(/img/icon/chest32.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
```

Instead I want the `background-image: url(/img/icon/cash32.png);`

I have tried adding .css

```
.pageTitleIcon
{
    background-image: url(/img/icon/cash32.png) !important;
}
```

Comment: Sorry no much idea, but is that the cash32.png in your static resource?

Comment: it's a Salesforce icons available for use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The icon is controlled by the `tabStyle` used on your page. If you want to use `cash32` instead of `chest32`, you need to have a tab that uses that style. For example, if `Opportunity` had this `tabStyle` selected, then you could do:

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Opportunity">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Dollar Store" />
</apex:page>
```

It has to be at the page level, though there is an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000aFSdAAM) out there to add this attribute to the `sectionHeader` tag.

---

If you really want to use CSS, you need to wrap your `url` in quotes. You also need to clear out the `background-position`, since by default the `tabStyle` sets the image based on a master sprite. If you're trying to override a `tabStyle` that's been set explicitly, it will look something like:

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Opportunity">
    <style>
        .opportunityTab .pageTitleIcon, .individualPalette .opportunityBlock .pageTitleIcon
        {
            background-position: initial;
            background-image: url('/img/icon/cash32.png');
        }
    </style>
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Dollar Store" />
</apex:page>
```

If you are not setting a `tabStyle` at all, then it would look like:

```
<apex:page>
    <style>
        .homeTab .pageTitleIcon, .individualPalette .homeBlock .pageTitleIcon
        {
            background-position: initial;
            background-image: url('/img/icon/cash32.png');
        }
    </style>
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Dollar Store" />
</apex:page>
```

---

## Related Reading: [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

> ### The !important exception
>
> When an important rule is used on a style declaration, this declaration overrides any other declarations. Although technically `!important` has nothing to do with specificity, it interacts directly with it. Using `!important` is **bad practice** and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets. When two conflicting declarations with the `!important` rule are applied to the same element, the declaration with greater specificity will be applied.
>
> Some rules of thumb:
>
> - **Always** look for a way to use specificity before even considering `!important`
> - **Only** use `!important` on page-specific CSS that overrides site-wide or foreign CSS (from external libraries, like Bootstrap or normalize.css).
> - **Never** use `!important` when you're writing a plugin/mashup.
> - **Never** use `!important` on site-wide CSS.

All of the emphasis above exists in the original document. Note the first bullet point:  ***Always** look for a way to use specificity before even considering `!important`*. That is why I used a long class selector with high specificity instead of using the `!important` flag.